# How safe is apache Commons-javaflow while using jasperreports

Tags: jasper-reports, apache-commons

I am using jasperreport and trying to pass an alternate report runner.

• net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRThreadSubreportRunner: The initial thread-based
implementation

• net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRContinuationSubreportRunner: A Javaflow-based
implementation

I am using the second one (for the reason, it runs on tomcat server, and creating threads wouldn't be good while writing subreports). The second one depends on commons-javaflow which is a sandbox version.

Not sure if I should use it, Could somebody suggest a better way.
Thanks

Comment: If you can tell in details what are you trying to do, maybe we can help better. And please specify the version of JasperReports you are using

Comment: I was using 3.7.2. The javaflow based report runner did not give properly formatted excel file. Some rows were missing, some were being printed in an out of proportion size.

Answer (score 3):

While javaflow is a sandbox component, it is fairly mature, and many people use it in production. If have worked out all of the class-loader/bytecode transformer steps you need to take, it should be safe to use.

I would write several automated tests (just to be sure), and then use it.

Answer (score 1):

*I hope i got the question right*
Actually JasperReports depends on many open source libraries, including Apache-Commons and iText among many others. I use JasperReports on multiple computers ranging from PCs to a mainframe. I believe you are safe.

Comment: Javaflow screwed up for large reports involving multiple subreports. There is no new release of javaflow. I guess nobody is supporting javaflow. Please correct me if I am wrong.